# База данных для нескольких языков

Tags: база-данных

в базе данных имеются данные для одного языка. Как хранить данные для других языков? Создавать отдельные поля под каждый и выбирать необходимый, в зависимости от языка клиента??

Comment: Способов много, прийдется выбрать один из. 1.Создать поля с другими языками (паралельно) 2. Создать привязаную таблицу к данной с идентификатором типа lang_id подвязкой parent_id и переводом foreing_name. Возможно ещё одним полем разшить на много таблиц. 3. (наверно самый маленький по-размеру) Создать словарь с переводом каждого слова или предложения, id из этого списка подвязать в основную таблицу (для ускорения). Если есть подвязка - оригинальный текст можно "опустить". Думаю это не весь список возможностей.

Comment: @nick_n_a можете отметить как ответ